# Using an alias in a where clause with calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that you cannot use an alias in a where clause, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the right query here. I need the below query to show our "unit counts" that have more than 10 of those type. I have tried a few different things but had no luck, below is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT location
    ,datekey
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN SmartSize = 'Small'
                THEN Unavailable + Vacant + Occupied
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS SmallUnitCount
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN SmartSize = 'Medium'
                THEN Unavailable + Vacant + Occupied
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS MediumUnitCount
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN SmartSize = 'Large'
                THEN Unavailable + Vacant + Occupied
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS LargeUnitCount
FROM statstable
GROUP BY location
    ,datekey
HAVING COUNT(unavailable + vacant + occupied) > 10
```

Comment: You can use an alias in the HAVING clause

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can use the little code button at the top after highlighting your code to put in a code format. (or indent it with 4 spaces). Also, bolding all of your text won't help in getting your question answered as this isn't craigslist.

Comment: ' show our "unit counts" that have more than 10 of those type.' is ambiguous - it could mean all have to have more than 10, in total there have to be more than ten or any one of them must be more than 10.

Comment: What i wish was possible is just to say:

where smallunitcount > 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
HAVING SUM(unavailable + vacant + occupied) > 10
```

If you want a particular unit type, you can do:

```
HAVING SmallUnitCount > 10
```

Comment: Well I do want the sum of the "unavailable, vacant, and occupied" but out of that sum I need to only select the ones that have a sum higher than 10